# Make server cache GET requests

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, cache

Like this:

Visitor (or user whatever) requests `site.com/page1/` trough GET, then `site.com/page1/` gets cached by the server, and all further requests of that page are served from cache, until a POST request is received.

When a POST request is received, cache gets flushed, page generated normally trough the script, and at the next GET request cache the page again until next POST request and so on...

Does it sound reliable and possible? Is there some Apache module that is able to do this?
I think that some shared hosts do this (so they can stuff many sites on a server), but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [`mod_cache`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cache.html) or a reverse proxy such as Squid, Varnish or nginx yet?  These cache any responses with the appropriate headers set.

You would need to write something in the code that handles your POST requests to invalidate the cache whenever it is required.